# Can you use matlab dynamic regular expressions to define a named token based on a previously captured token?

Tags: regex, matlab

I'd like to try and parse out a structure that uses a previously captured named token, and use the name in that token as the name for another token. Is that possible?

for example, for the string `foo:bar` I'd like to capture the token `field` as `foo`, and the token `foo` as `bar`

I think it should look something like this:

`data = regexp(text,'(?<field>\w+)...((??\?\<$<field>\>[^;]));','names');`

But so far I am having no success.

Comment: Maybe just `'(?<field>\w+):(?<foo>\w+)'`?

Comment: The idea though is that there are multiple such lines, not just foo. One might be foo:bar, another fizz:buzz, etc. and they are all in the same file I'm reading so it basically needs to be a single dynamic expression

Comment: Then it is not possible.

Comment: Sounds like you'd just be making your code more complex. Keep your code and your data separate. The string "foo" is data, don't try to put it into your code by naming tokens after it.

Comment: This is a one-off procedure to help me reorganize something that would take much longer to do by hand, it won't be done repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first split the string using split

```
splt_str = split('foo:bar', ':');
```

then, use the seperated string in order to fill a struct

```
data.(splt_str{1}) = splt_str{2};
```

This approach hinges around the fact that a struct can be filled by passing a string as a fieldname inside to brackets (). See [this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) help page.